# clear text when it success else the text should not be cleared in android

Tags: android

```
     protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
           // editTextName.setText("");
            //editTextEmail.setText("");
            //editTextPassword.setText("");
            //editTextPhone.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sToast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

If the detail is successfull means the edit text field should be cleared else it should not be cleared .

Comment: When it is success use editText.getText().clear(); else keep the text.

Answer (score 0):

return something from doInBackground() and check that in onPostExecute(). set the editText's depending upon the conditions.